# How to perform multithreading with PowerShell?

Tags: multithreading, powershell

How can we use multithread in PowerShell.
My Query is below:

I have a root folder which has various base folder under it.
I want to sync the folders from server to another using SFTP on remote.
So I want all the folders from the left folder structure to get synced to another server folder using multithreading so that the transfer becomes faster.

I am using WinSCP.net `SynchronizeDirectories` to sync, but its quite slow.

Please suggest a better way if any one can.

Comment: What makes you think it would be faster?

Comment: i wanted to sync each individual folder in separate thread, in that way i think it might become faster.My assumption might be wrong,please suggest a better way if you can.

Comment: i am hardly 2 days old to powershell scripts.you can suggest better ways.

Comment: How can you multi-thread vs how can you transport files faster are 2 different questions.

Comment: I can suggest you to have a faster internet connection

Comment: Actually i am WinSCPnet SynchronizeDirectories which checks with each files timestamp and each folder structure.My folder structure is quite deep and moreover i have lot of image and video files also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150286/discussion-between-abhijit-and-alex-weitz).

Comment: Please start with an actual problem description. How slow *exactly* is "quite slow". What amount of data do you need to synchronize? What are your time constraints? What is the available bandwidth?

Comment: i never really checked it but it didnt end in 2 days also.we need to do it in around 4 hrs for around 100 gb.

Comment: You need to be able to transfer not less than 70 megabits per second. What is the claimed speed of your connection, and what is your actual throughput?